# custom posts on different page

Tags: custom-post-types, pages

> i have a custom post on my website, i
>   just want that the all post from
>   custom post types should be published
>   on a separate **page** which will be
>   "Blog", is this possible?

the code worked, i edited the code
this is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog template
*/
get_header(); 

$blog_query = new WP_Query;
$blog_query->query( 'post_type=uni' ); // <-- Your args on this line
?>

<div id="content" class="col-full">
<div id="main" class="col-left">
<?php if( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : $blog_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="featured post">
    <h2 class="title fl"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>
    </br>
    <p class="fr">

                   <span class="small"><span class="post-category"><?php the_category(' ') ?></span></span>

               </p>
               <p class="post-meta">

                        <span class="small"><?php _e('Featured Venue &#124;', 'woothemes'); ?></span>

                        <span class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link(__('0 Reviews', 'woothemes'), __('1 Review', 'woothemes'), __('% Reviews', 'woothemes')); ?></span>

                    </p>
                    <div class="entry">

                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                </div>

    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>
</div>

<?php 
get_footer();
```

but when i click on the title of the blog page,
it takes me to a page where content of the posts come without div tag, and on the menu its on the home page
check this image
[image]
in this image everything looks fine, this is what i wanted

in this when i click on the post i.e. title it comes this way

check this image
[image]
the menu is pointing on home and there is no `div` tag in the post

Comment: *"I have a custom post on my website"*; do you mean _"post"_ or *"postS" (plural?)*  If you want them on Blog, and I assume you mean a list of posts, where do you want the list of `post_type='post'`?

Comment: se what i am telling you to tell is, i have a custom post type, whenever i write a post from this it should directly publish on blog page, instead on home

Comment: you can refer my answer on this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175120/custom-posts-on-different-pages/270656#270656

Comment: you can refer my answer on same question on this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175120/custom-posts-on-different-pages/270656#270656

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a page, call it blog.

Create a page template and fetch posts from the custom type.

Attach the template to the page.

Save.

## Example Page Template

You can use any parameters in the query line that you would with [query posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog template
*/
get_header(); 

$blog_query = new WP_Query;
$blog_query->query( 'post_type=mycustomtype' ); // <-- Your args on this line
?>

<div id="content">

<?php if( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : $blog_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post">
        <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>

<?php 
get_footer();
```

Comment: hey your code worked, but i made some changes, instead of `the_content` i used `the_excerpt` which works, but when i click on the title, it should open the content in a page like single.php, and it should be in the same menu i.e. blog, but when i click on the title, it opens a page which contains no <div> and it opens in the home menu, check my original answer

Comment: At a guess, whichever page renders your **home** page doesn't include the div you're referring to?