# Different Limit number of post on different archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I set post per page from setting>maximum post per page to 20. I have 2 different custom post types 'book' and 'author' for archives of each of them. I want to load different number of post in page. I want to load 20 book per page in book archive and 5 post in author archive in each page. I also use WP-PageNavi plugin.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'Author','paged' => $paged,'posts_per_page' =>5 ); 
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="writer-link col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

    <div class="writer-row1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 image-right">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail',array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 pull-right writer-content">
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <h4><?php the_field('auth-trans'); ?></h4>  
    <?php if ( get_field('writer-bio') ) { 
        echo '<p>'.get_field('writer-bio').'</p>';} ?>

            <span>...</span>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

   <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>           

    <div class="wp-pagenavi row">
        <div id="wp_page_numbers text-center col-sm-6 center-margin">
            <ul>
                <li class="active_page text-center"><?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $loop )); } ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
```

No problem with book archive: it loads 20 posts. But I don't know how I can make author page to load just 5 post per page and after it has loaded 5 first posts it is going to next page.

Answer (score 4):

add below code in functions.php file , here "event" is custom post type (change it as per your post type) , so here it will display 6 post on events list page , also you need to copy default archive.php file and copy and create new archive-event.php (replace event with your post type).

```
 function custom_type_archive_display($query) {
    if (is_post_type_archive('event')) {
         $query->set('posts_per_page',6);
         $query->set('orderby', 'date' );
         $query->set('order', 'DESC' );
        return;
    }     
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_type_archive_display');
```

Hope this Helps :)

More detail how to list custom post on custom page refer this link [Custom Posts on Different Pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175120/custom-posts-on-different-pages/270656#270656)

Comment: This is a nice answer, thanks !

Comment: Still works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the query arguments dependend on the type of archive you are generating (which WP already knows from the [page slug](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#URLs)). Luckily there is a test for that, called [`is_post_type_archive`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive). In the beginning of your code you would include this:

```
if (is_post_type_archive('books')) {
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Books','paged' => $paged,'posts_per_page' =>20 );
  }
elseif (is_post_type_archive('author')) {
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Author','paged' => $paged,'posts_per_page' =>5 );
  }
```

Comment: you mean in function.php I have to add it?

Comment: No, replace the third line of the code you posted. Note that I don't know what template page this is, but assume it is `archive.php`. Or a custom one for this post type?

Comment: I add ` $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Author','paged' => $paged,'posts_per_page' =>5 );` because this custom post type have separate html page. I gave each of page above line with different post per page, but still have problem. when I click on the second page of author it shows 404 page

Comment: But you do get 5 and 20 posts on the respective archives?

Comment: I need to load 20 post in archive book in each page and load 5 author in author archive.I add post per page 5 to archive-author.php and 20 to archive-book.php and set max read to 20. but dosen't work fine

Comment: If you already have separate templates for each post type my answer doesn't make sense.